# How do I fix my leaky shower pipe?

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak

I'm in the process of building out my basement (as I've been for the past 3 years). Finally got around to installing a shower head pipe (leading out from the wall) yesterday, and it looks like the bottom part of this leaks when I open the valve. This is a brand-new installation, and I have tried pretty much everything I could think of...

- rolled teflon tape twice around the pipe, no difference
- rolled teflon tape appx 5 times around the pipe, no difference
- tried screwing the pipe in without any tape, no difference
- checked for any warpage inside the wall, nope, everything looks round enough

I'm not sure what else I can do to fix this. Even opening the valve just a bit (10-20%) initially shoots water out from below the showerhead pipe, which then settles into a definite multi-drop drip (and leaks into the drywall around the opening).

Any thoughts? Should I replace the in-wall pipe? I think I can do that without much pain (it's drywall, after all), but would rather not.

Edited to add: it's not the showerhead-to-pipe connection that's leaking; instead, it's the pipe-to-wall connection.

Answer (score 1):

> Edited to add: it's not the showerhead-to-pipe connection that's leaking; instead, it's the pipe-to-wall connection.

I think you figured it out. It is possible your drop ear fitting in the wall is cracked or you have a bad connection to it.

Normally, the plumbers pressure test the whole system before the drywall goes on. You may have to remove some drywall to repair the pipe and then patch the drywall.

Major bummer but all things can be fixed eventually.

Good luck!